# Counting states in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with string values of states and want to return how many values of each state. I want to use python and pandas to answer this question. I know its basic, but I appreciate the help.

the data frame is as follows;

```
States
California
Nevada
California
Washington
Washington
Washington
```

Which should return

```
California - 2 
Washington - 3
Nevada     - 1
```

Comment: `df.States.value_counts()`

Comment: thank you! I swear I tried that so many times. But user error.... Thanks

Comment: I recommend you close the question with @wwnde answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with value counts. First I made the data frame with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'States': ['California',
                              'Nevada',
                              'California',
                              'Washington',
                              'Washington',
                              'Washington']})
```

Then use the value counts function:

```
df['States'].value_counts()
```

That outputs:

[image]